# Не работает многопоточность ThreadPoolExecutor Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

```
def method(args, num):
    ...

# Массив чисел от 50 до 100
nums = [x for x in range(50, 100)]
# Создаю массивы с агрументами и каждым числом
map_args = [(args, a) for a in nums]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_threads) as exe:
    exe.map(method, map_args)
```

Почему-то не работает, сразу же завершается работа с кодом 0. Не могу понять почему?
Может как-то иначе аргументы в метод передавать? `exe.map(method, map_args)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что метод принимает 2 аргумента `args` и `num`, а я передаю только 1 - `map_args`. Как передавать 2 аргумента я не знаю, но можно все еще передавать `map_args`, заменив `method(args, num)` на `method(data)`, и распаковывать `data` - `args, num = data`.

```
def method(data):
    args, num = data
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно ещё проитерироваться по результатам маппинга:

```
result = exe.map(method, map_args)
for res in result:
   print(res)
```

С передачей аргументов у вас, кажется, тоже проблемы, но главное то, что вы не потребляете результаты вызова.

Comment: А как-то можно без итерирования обойтись? В result все None, кроме того единственного res, который мне нужен.

Comment: И как можно исправить передачу аргументов?

Comment: Ну можно просто взять `list(exe.map)` и оно само проитерируется с помощью `list`. А насчёт аргументов, я не знаю, как сделать красиво, но вы можете оставить один аргумент у функции - туда будет попадать кортеж из переданных значений. Можете распаковать этот кортеж и получить таким образом переменные.